# Which sources bring down the reason for us giving Maaser and Tzedakah?

Tags: sources-mekorot

It's brought down in certain sefarim, regarding the giving of Maaseros and Tzedakah, that in reality, everything belongs to the Rebono Shel Olam, and whatever you receive (produce, food)
is a Matanah (present) from Him.....but, he wants you to give something back to Him (one tenth)by distributing it to the Aniyim (poor), the Leviyim (Levites) etc.

Where can I find this idea brought down?

Comment: Are you answering your own question? If so, put the answer in the answers section, and include actual sources. If not, please make it clearer in the body of the question what, exactly, you are looking for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Tur Yoreh Deah 247 - כי יש לו לדעת שאין הממון שלו אלא פקדון לעשות בו רצון המפקיד וזה רצונו שיחלק לעניים ממנו וזהו החלק הטובה שיהיה לו ממנו כדכתיב והלך לפניך צדקך

Comment: See T. Zohar 31a for example. At the root it's all to repair Chava's and Adam's premature actions: ובגין דא חלה ודאי איהי פקודא דאתמני לאתתא, דבגינה מת אדם דאיהו חלתו של עולם, צריכה איהי לאפרשא חלה, ולאפקא לה מעסתה, דאיהי טפה דילה, להחזירה על אדם: